# Why does the Fairy Tail anime have a nautical theme?

Tags: fairy-tail

I've been watching the *Fairy Tail* anime, and I'm noticing a large number of nautical references, from the logo, to the music, and others that have slipped my mind.

The logo itself features the tops of the letters forming a wave-like pattern and the top of the "T" resembling an anchor as well as the final "L" has a tail that appears to be in the shape of a fish hook. This hook shape also appears in the guilds logo along with a harpoon.

As for music, I cannot help but hear the repetition of the *Can-Can* music as well as once what sounded like *Land of Hope and Glory*.

If anyone has any information on why there is the inclusion of such things I would graciously appreciate it. I may however be hallucinating in which case I'm sorry to have wasted your time

Answer (score 0):

**I think you're hallucinating**

Considering the HUGE cast size, the various other logos and the 20+ opening songs of different styles, and some variations of the logo, it's hard to say they have a single theme.

The logo itself, btw, it just a fairy with a tail. [This picture](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100803104709/fairytail/images/c/c5/Fairy_Tail_former_building.jpg) of a different version of the logo seems to help people with seeing it.

But if I have some time later, i'll check out the music and such to see if i can find some themes between them. Let me know if you have any more specifics that point towards that theme.